# php glob function - no polish letters

Tags: php

I have problem with my function, everything working fine, but when name of catalog have a polish letters like "ś ć ł ó", browser give me a black diamonds with questionmarks, my document have meta charset UTF-8.

```
                $dir = glob("flash/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);        
                usort($dir, function($a, $b){
                    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
                });

         echo '<h4>' . basename($plk) . '</h4>';
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filesystem might be in different encoding, make it a setting in your application so it will work both on your windows PC and on the server. Then convert to this encoding when saving files and from this encoding when reading:

```
echo '<h4>' . iconv($settings['filesystem_encoding'], 'utf-8', basename($plk)) . '</h4>';
```

Comment: ok, thats work fine :) but can I convert whole $dir to UTF-8 ?

Comment: @Artur you need to do this inside `foreach` loop, or using `array_map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `urlencode` function:

```
echo '<h4>' . urlencode(basename($plk)) . '</h4>';
```